# Matrix multiplication using slicing. Python

Tags: python, slice, matrix-multiplication

I have the following code:

```
from numpy import *
a = random.rand(3,4)
b = random.rand(4,2)
c = linspace(0,0,6)
c.shape = (3,2)
for i in range(a.shape[0]): 
  for j in range(b.shape[1]): 
      for k in range(b.shape[0]): 
         c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
for r in c: 
  print "C = ", r
```

But I need to change the last (innermost) loop and I need to use slicing. As I understood I have to do something like this:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]): 
 for j in range(b.shape[1]): 
     c[i][j] += a[i][0:l-1] * b[0:l-1][j]
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Could somebody help me and give a hint how to do it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity is this for school, or are you actually trying to do matrix multiplication for some realistic purpose?  If the latter, use `np.dot`.  Do not loop over Numpy arrays element-wise in Python if you can help it.

Comment: @Iguananaut Actually I need to calculate and compare the time of calculation of these two methods and np.dot.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do here is the dot product of the row vector from `a`, and the column vector from `b`:

```
c[i][j] += a[i][0:l-1] * b[0:l-1][j]
```

which would be

```
c[i][j] = np.dot(a[i], b[:][j])
```

which is the same as

```
sum([a_*b_ for a_,b_ in zip(a[i],b[:][j])])
```

or

```
sum(a[i]*b[:][j])
```

but faster.

However, if you're using `np.dot`, anyways:

```
c = np.dot(a,b)
```

is definitely faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an helper function that creates a ListOfLists (a lol) of `r` rows, each composed of `c` columns:

```
In [1]: def lol(r,c): return [[i*c+j for j in range(c)] for i in range(r)]
```

and create two list of lists

```
In [2]: a = lol(2,5) ; b = lol(5,4)
```

We want to verify that our code below, meant to do a matrix product using two lol's is working correctly, so we create two `ndarray`s from `a` and `b` and form their inner product

```
In [3]: from numpy import array

In [4]: aa = array(a) ; ab = array(b) ; aa.dot(ab)
Out[4]: 
array([[120, 130, 140, 150],
       [320, 355, 390, 425]])
```

Now, we can test our code for the inner, or matrix, product of two lols

```
In [5]: [[sum(x*y for x, y in zip(ar,bc)) for bc in zip(*b)] for ar in a]
Out[5]: [[120, 130, 140, 150], [320, 355, 390, 425]]
```

It's ok, isn't it? (I have to say that in a first iteration of the code I came out with the transpose of the result...).

Now that we have a bit of confidence, let's try  with something more substantial

```
In [6]: a = lol(200,50) ; b = lol(50,400)

In [7]: aa = array(a) ; ab = array(b)

In [8]: %timeit c = aa.dot(ab)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.53 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit c = [[sum(x*y for x, y in zip(ar,bc)) for bc in zip(*b)] for ar in a]
1 loops, best of 3: 469 ms per loop
```

As you can see, `numpy` is two order of magnitude faster than operating on lists, but it is more interesting, in the context of the OP question, to try our list code on the `ndarray`s:

```
In [10]: %timeit c = [[sum(x*y for x, y in zip(ar,bc)) for bc in zip(*ab)] for ar in aa] 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop
```

Oh, if you have `numpy` arrays it's way better to use the array methods rather than operating on the individual elements... but wait, we have a faster alternative to the inner `zip`:

```
In [11]: %timeit c = [[sum(x*y for x, y in zip(ar,bc)) for bc in ab.T] for ar in aa]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop

In [12]:
```

no, even if we use the transpose property of a `ndarray` we have the same results.

Summary: never ever use individually accessed `numpy` array's elements to do heavy computational lifting...

---

Thank you to `ipython` and its `%timeit` *magic* that made this rambling easier and fun (for me).